# Appcelerator - How to disable system sounds when tapping on images and other views?

Tags: android, events, audio, click, titanium

I'm building an Android app using Appcelerator. My problem is that everywhere I tap on the screen the phone plays a system sound. But I want to play system default sound on tapping buttons only.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add this item into your style file to mute sound effects:

```
<item name="android:soundEffectsEnabled">false</item>
```